# Identifier SDO_RDF.CREATE_RDF_NETWORK must be declared ORACLE 12c JENA

Tags: oracle, rdf, jena, semantic-web, oracle12c

I am working with semantic (RDF/OWL) data and want to store it in Oracle 12c. I have installed all necessary softwares.

I have created a pluggable database PROJOWL and trying to create a table within that to store the RDF data.

The steps I follow are from [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RDFRM/sdo_rdf_concepts.htm#RDFRM602) (go to 1.11)

```
Step 1: CREATE TABLESPACE rdf_users
 DATAFILE 'rdf_users.dat' SIZE 128M REUSE
 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 64M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
 SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;

Step 2: EXECUTE SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_NETWORK('rdf_users');
```

This is where I get the error

```
SQL> EXECUTE SDO_RDF.CREATE_RDF_NETWORK('rdf_users');
BEGIN SDO_RDF.CREATE_RDF_NETWORK('rdf_users'); END;

*
Error on line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: Identifier SDO_RDF.CREATE_RDF_NETWORK must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Not sure what to do to resolve this. I am new and trying to run the example in the documentation is the only way for me to get me understand write code for my data. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your step 2 is to call `SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_NETWORK`, but you've shown you actually ran `SDO_RDF.CREATE_RDF_NETWORK`. [They should both work](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RDFRM/sdo_rdf_concepts.htm#RDFRM612) (I think), but do you get the same error with the new name? Which user are you running it as? And are you sure the package/option is installed?

Comment: I get the same error with SEM_APIS. I am running it as SYS user. Which package are you talking about ?

Comment: no but i have enabled the RDF semantic support by following https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RDFRM/sem_enable.htm#RDFRM119

Comment: I get the same error. Let me start from the beginning. step1] SQLPLUS SYS/PASSWORD as SYSDBA step2] ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = PROJOWL (set pluggable database) step3] Create TableSpace command step4] ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = MDSYS step5] EXECUTE COMMAND gives error

Comment: enabled RDF support by running catsem.sql (table is created in MDSYS.rdf.parameter). Would it better if I create a new PDB and start all over again ? Does my old PDB  or CDB affect the new one ?

Comment: Looking at what `catsem` does it should have created all the grants and synonyms you need, to make my earlier comment about the schema redundant... so if it was run in the PROJOWL container I'm not sure what's wrong. Sorry, I don't have the same environment to try to recreate.